# How to groupby substring with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I try to make a query to MySQL, but I don't know if it is possible.
I try to group by with a substring. I have 1 column with paths like

```
a/b/c
a/g/b
a/g/c
a/b/d
a/b/e
b/c/e
b/c/d
a/g/a
```

and I want it grouped like:

```
a/b/c
a/b/d
a/b/e

a/g/a
a/g/b
a/g/c

b/c/d
b/c/e
```

can I do this with a query, or do I need to do this programmatically ?

Comment: `GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 2)`

Comment: can you give me the full query ?

Comment: Provide sample source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (formatted code) and desired output for this data (formatted table). If the algo is not obvious one then add some explanations.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM field_data_tbl
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(xpath '/', 2)


Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'

Comment: [SUBSTRING_INDEX(*str*,*delim*,*count*)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). If you got 1582 then you did something wrongly. In shown code - a comma is lost.

Comment: `SELECT *` contradicts with `GROUP BY`. Do you really need in grouping? maybe you need in sorting?

Comment: if sorting also creates that groups that i need I'm a MySQL noob I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward if you can use regex to extract the relevant part of the string. Then, use dense_rank over it to get a numeric id which signify the group you need...

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (path varchar(200));
insert into test values 
('aaaa/bgghhhyygj/cdfsf'),
('aaaa/ggghhhyygj/bdfsf'),
('aaaa/ggghhhyygj/cdfsf'),
('aaaa/bgghhhyygj/ddfsf'),
('aaaa/bgghhhyygj/edfsf'),
('baaa/cgghhhyygj/edfsf'),
('baaa/cgghhhyygj/ddfsf'),
('aaaa/ggghhhyygj/adfsf');

select * from test;

select 
    dense_rank() over (order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(path, '^.*?/.*?/') asc) as group_id,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(path, '^.*?/.*?/') as str_extract,
    path
from test;
```

> ```
> path
> aaaa/bgghhhyygj/cdfsf
> aaaa/ggghhhyygj/bdfsf
> aaaa/ggghhhyygj/cdfsf
> aaaa/bgghhhyygj/ddfsf
> aaaa/bgghhhyygj/edfsf
> baaa/cgghhhyygj/edfsf
> baaa/cgghhhyygj/ddfsf
> aaaa/ggghhhyygj/adfsf
> group_id  str_extract path
> 1 aaaa/bgghhhyygj/    aaaa/bgghhhyygj/cdfsf
> 1 aaaa/bgghhhyygj/    aaaa/bgghhhyygj/ddfsf
> 1 aaaa/bgghhhyygj/    aaaa/bgghhhyygj/edfsf
> 2 aaaa/ggghhhyygj/    aaaa/ggghhhyygj/bdfsf
> 2 aaaa/ggghhhyygj/    aaaa/ggghhhyygj/cdfsf
> 2 aaaa/ggghhhyygj/    aaaa/ggghhhyygj/adfsf
> 3 baaa/cgghhhyygj/    baaa/cgghhhyygj/edfsf
> 3 baaa/cgghhhyygj/    baaa/cgghhhyygj/ddfsf
> ```

---

**EDIT**: As @akina mentioned, it is easier to just use SUBSTRING_INDEX() for the second iteration of '/'

```
select 
    dense_rank() over (order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', 2) asc) as group_id,
    path
from test;
```

Comment: Regex is even more than excess in shown case. You can hammer nails with a microscope. But this is not reasonable.

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR is not a function in mysql only in oracle

Comment: @vue-dev https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

Comment: yes i see but is there a other way for MySQL 5.6 ?

Comment: @Akina: Yes, you could also do it using a substring+(find 1st instance then next instance of '/'), maybe it is more efficient and verbose, but I went with a simpler approach which is generally applicable (even if paths are more than three folders deep e,g, 'a/b/c/d/e').. I understand there will be a cost implication..

Comment: @vue-dev When the version is not specified then the most recent assumed. Edit your question, add version info, and add according tag.

Comment: *you could also do it using a substring .. even if paths are more than three folders deep* SUBSTRING_INDEX(), not SUBSTRING().

Comment: Thanks @akina Just read the documentation on SUBSTRIN_INDEX(), didnt know it existed :D it is exactly what OP needs.. if he was using the latest version